# How to create switch block in Java?

Tags: java

I have 2 classes: in first class I have static method which returned int value, and const - NETWORK_EXCEPTION (public static final int NETWORK_EXCEPTION=1), and in second class I get returned value from static method and use it for switch block:

```
int response=NetworkUtilities.addNewUser(email, name, number);
switch (response) {
    case (NetworkUtilities.NETWORK_EXCEPTION):
        break;
}
```

But I always get following message: "case expressions must be constant expressions". How can create switch block? May be I need to use enum? Give me an example or fix my code please.

```
public static int NETWORK_EXCEPTION=-1;
public static int EXIST_EXCEPTION=0;
```

Comment: can you post the actual decleration of the constant NETWORK_EXCEPTION?

Comment: There is no `final` in your `public static final int`.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Now you've posted the declaration, it's clear:

```
public static int NETWORK_EXCEPTION=-1;
public static int EXIST_EXCEPTION=0;
```

should be

```
public static final int NETWORK_EXCEPTION=-1;
public static final int EXIST_EXCEPTION=0;
```

Note the `final` part - without that they're not constants. (In your earlier question text you claim that you *had* declared it as `final` - it pays to be precise about this :)

As an aside, given that you're *declaring* these with names including "exception" are you sure you shouldn't just be throwing exceptions?

---

That should be absolutely fine. Short but complete program to demonstrate:

```
class Constants {
    public static final int NETWORK_EXCEPTION = 1;
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        switch (value) {
            case Constants.NETWORK_EXCEPTION:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Are you *sure* it's declared as `final`? And with a value of just `1` rather than the result of some method call?

If you could post a similar short but complete program which fails, that would help.